# Date type object gets converted into String while returning using res.json

Tags: express, mongoose

I have a date object, lets say `var myDate = new Date()`.

Now when I am returning it using `res.json({msg: {myDate: myDate}})` the `myDate` object gets converted into string.I want that the type of `myDate` should persist. I am using mongoose ODM and express.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON doesn't have a date type, which means you have to convert it to date when it reaches the front-end. The JSON spec is [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf).

Comment: this is the correct answer. Also, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on `JSON.stringify()` says this: "... some objects like Date will be a string after JSON.parse()."